# Is $\operatorname{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ isomorphic to $G\rtimes\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R})$ for some group $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, automorphism-group

The current question is motivated by the possibility of existence of an analogy between the absolute Galois group of the rationals and the dihedral group of order $2n$ seen as the isometry group of a convex regular $n$-gon. Indeed, a theorem of Artin says that the only elements of finite order of the absolute Galois group of the rationals, denoted by $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$, are the identity and the complex conjugation.

So can one write $G_{\mathbb{Q}}\cong H\rtimes\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R})$ for some normal subgroup $H$ of $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$?

Comment: Given a finite index subgroup $H$ of $G_\Bbb{Q}$ we always look at $K=\overline{\Bbb{Q}}^H$ the subfield fixed by $H$, it is a finite extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ and if $H$ is normal then $\sigma(K)=\overline{\Bbb{Q}}^{\sigma H\sigma^{-1}}=\overline{\Bbb{Q}}^H=K$ so $K/\Bbb{Q}$ is Galois and $Gal(K/\Bbb{Q})=G_\Bbb{Q}/H$. If $H$ is of index 2 then $K/\Bbb{Q}$ is a quadratic extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "the" complex conjugation I think you mean fixing an embedding $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{C}$.

Otherwise, it doesn't make sense to view $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R})$ as a subgroup of $G_\mathbb{Q}$.

Take any imaginary quadratic extension $E/\mathbb{Q}$ (e.g. $E = \mathbb{Q}[i]$) and let $H$ be the subgroup $G_E$ of $G_\mathbb{Q}$.

It is then a normal subgroup and we have the short exact sequence
$$1\rightarrow G_E\rightarrow G_\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow 1,$$ because the complex conjugation induces an isomorphism $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R})\simeq \operatorname{Gal}(E/\mathbb{Q})$.

This sequence splits via the embedding of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ into $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.